# AdSense and Analytics Connection is not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

i have connected my google analytics account to my adsense account. But no menupoint for adsense is shown in analytics. Although i have now waited some days and both systems say in configuration, that the accounts are connected.

1. Where is the adsense menupoint in analytics normally located?
2. What could be the problem, that the connection is not working? Cause

Thx.
René

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can access integrated stats on analytics property page at BEHAVIOR -> Publisher menu.